# Pyspark efficiently create patterns within each window

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark, data-science, tabula

I want to create a base dataframe from the existing one, which does not contain all I want, for example, I have the dataframe collecting the number of candies each people (tracked by "id") bought each year-month (but in this case each person didn't buy candies every month)

```
|id|year_month|num_of_candies_bought
  1  2022-01           5
  1  2022-03          10
  1  2022-04           2
```

What I want is that to track them by fix the year-month I'm interested like this (for the first 5 months this year)

```
|id|year_month|num_of_candies_bought
  1  2022-01           5
  1  2022-02           0
  1  2022-03          10
  1  2022-04           2
  1  2022-05           0
```

I think one way to do this is to use "crossjoin" but it turns out that this takes long time to process. Is there any way to do this without any join? In my work the first dataframe is very very huge (a million rows for instance) while the second is just fixed (like in this case only 5 rows) and much much smaller. Is it possible (if it is needed to use crossjoin) to improve performance drastically?

P.S. I want this to seperate each person (so I need to use window.partition thing)

Comment: what would be the start date and end date ? The min/max on the whole dataframe ? or the min/max for for each id ? or an input date ?

Comment: min max in this case are 20220101 and 20220531 respectively for every ids. @Steven

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd simply add a `0` (zero) line for each id and each id and year_month.
Let's assume `df` is your dataframe.

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

# generate a list of all year_month you need
year_month = ["2022-01", "2022-02", "2022-03", "2022-04", "2022-05"]

df_id = (
    df.select("id")
    .distinct()
    .withColumn("num_of_candies_bought", F.lit(0))
    .withColumn("year_month", F.explode(F.array(*map(F.lit, year_month))))
)

df = (
    df.unionByName(df_id)
    .groupBy("id", "year_month")
    .agg(F.sum("num_of_candies_bought").alias("num_of_candies_bought"))
)
```

Comment: Is the explode efficient? I suppose it is much more effective than join?

Comment: @W.Wongcharoenbhorn a `join` implies map/reduce  expensive operations. An `explode` is just a map. therefore, way more efficient.

Comment: The first statement should be
df_id = (
    df.select("id")
    .distinct()
    .withColumn("year_month", F.array([F.lit(x) for x in year_month]))
    .withColumn("num_of_candies_bought", F.lit(0))
    .withColumn("year_month", F.explode("year_month"))
)

Comment: @W.Wongcharoenbhorn indeed. I edited the answer